# PL/SQL XML CDATA

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, xml-parsing

I have pulled the FCO Audit trail from some composites in Oracle enterprise manager. That Audit trail is put in a table as a CLOB. I then pull the CLOB and parse it using DBMS_XMLPARSER.parseclob to pull the component data I need as a DBMS_XMLDOM.domdocument.

The problem is I need a group of tags found under a CDATA section. Since those are also XML formatted I would like to create a sub domdocument and parse it the same way but when I do that the tags are all #text.

I can proceed to just edit is as a string but a better solution would be to be able to pull the tags using the oracle provided dbms_xmldom procedures.

```
DECLARE
CURSOR xml_results IS
(SELECT fco_audittrail
   FROM xxyl.xyl_all_payloads_modp
  WHERE fco_compositeinstanceid = 2325466);

indomdoc       DBMS_XMLDOM.domdocument;
innode         DBMS_XMLDOM.domnode;
myparser       DBMS_XMLPARSER.parser;
l_children     DBMS_XMLDOM.domnodelist;

sub_indomdoc   DBMS_XMLDOM.domdocument;
sub_children   DBMS_XMLDOM.domnodelist;
sub_myparser   DBMS_XMLPARSER.parser;

BEGIN
  myparser := DBMS_XMLPARSER.newparser;
  sub_myparser := DBMS_XMLPARSER.newparser;

  FOR xmlr IN xml_results LOOP

  DBMS_XMLPARSER.parseclob(myparser, xmlr.fco_audittrail);
  indomdoc := DBMS_XMLPARSER.getdocument(myparser);
  innode   := DBMS_XMLDOM.makenode(indomdoc);

  l_children :=
    DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.selectnodes(n => DBMS_XMLDOM.makenode(DBMS_XMLDOM.getdocumentelement(indomdoc)), pattern => '//text()', namespace => NULL);

  -- iterate through the node list
  FOR i IN 0 .. DBMS_XMLDOM.getlength(l_children) - 1 LOOP
    IF DBMS_XMLDOM.getnodename(DBMS_XMLDOM.item(l_children, i)) = '#cdata-section' THEN
      IF DBMS_XMLDOM.getnodevalue(DBMS_XMLDOM.item(l_children, i)) LIKE '%<Invoke_InvoiceImport_process_InputVariable>%' THEN

      DBMS_XMLPARSER.parsebuffer(sub_myparser,DBMS_XMLDOM.getnodevalue(DBMS_XMLDOM.item(l_children, i)));
      sub_indomdoc := DBMS_XMLPARSER.getdocument(sub_myparser);
      sub_children := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.selectnodes(n => DBMS_XMLDOM.makenode(DBMS_XMLDOM.getdocumentelement(sub_indomdoc)), pattern => '//text()', namespace => NULL);

      FOR j IN 0 .. DBMS_XMLDOM.getlength(sub_children) - 1 LOOP
                  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(DBMS_XMLDOM.getnodename(DBMS_XMLDOM.item(sub_children, j))
                             || ': '
                             || DBMS_XMLDOM.getnodevalue(DBMS_XMLDOM.item(sub_children, j)));
           END LOOP;
         END IF;
       END IF;
     END LOOP;

    DBMS_XMLDOM.freedocument(indomdoc);
    DBMS_XMLDOM.freedocument(sub_indomdoc);
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_XMLPARSER.freeparser(myparser);
  DBMS_XMLPARSER.freeparser(sub_myparser);
END;
```

Comment: Why are you doing all the procedural parsing stuff/DOM traversal  when you can use direct selects with xpath and the "extract" functions? Also, you do not show sample data and expected output, so not really possible to assist.

Comment: Started down that path but failed there with the same problem. I cannot figure out how to render the CDATA so the tag are accessible by name. It keeps rendering the name of the node as #TEXT.